# 0/1 - Knapsak and similar problem on 2D Matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

**Problem**: Given a  2d matrix of **item weights**, their respective **costs** in another 2d matrix and **max capacity** **W**. Find the optimal selection such that profit is maximum(i.e sum of costs is maximum) and total items weight remains within capacity.

---

Now, Another constraint is you are **allowed to choose only a single item from each column** or choose no item from that column.

---

The example below isn't the optimal solution!

---

[image: This may help if it's not clear]

Comment: Sounds like it is in NP - by reduction from normal knapsack...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that!

Comment: Are you sure this problem is solvable in reasonable time? Who gave you this question? It seems like it must be solved with bruteforce since it is very similar to regular knapsack which we know must be solved with bruteforce .

Comment: No, we can improve a lot on naive approach for 0/1 knapsack, Dynamic Programming.